# Issues inserting node in binary tree in-order-insertion

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

I am working on creating a priority queue with a binary tree.  For insertions, I have to insert new nodes level by level. Then I will heap sort the tree after each insertion.
The code below is what I have, but it seem to not add properly.
Can anyone help?

```
Node * getNextInsertionPointer(Node * root){
    int h = height(root);
    int i;
    Node * leafLocation = NULL;
    for (i=1; i<=h; i++){
        leafLocation = traverseThrougTree(root, i);
    }
    return leafLocation;
}

Node * traverseThrougTree(Node * root, int level){
    if (root == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    if (level == 1){
        if (root->leftChild == NULL){
            return root -> leftChild;
        }else if (root -> rightChild == NULL){
            return root -> rightChild;
        }
    }else if (level > 1){
        traverseThrougTree(root->leftChild, level-1);
        traverseThrougTree(root->rightChild, level-1);
    }
}
```

UPDATE
When I manually traverse the tree, I find NULL, it is only adding the root.
Insertion code:

```
void insertQueue(Queue *queue, void *data){
    if (queue == NULL) {
        printf("Heap not initialized.\n");
        return;
    }
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Memory for Data is not allocated.\n");
        return;
    }
    Node * newNode = createQueueNode(data);
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("Node not allocated.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("New node.\n");
    // If the queue tree.
    if (queue -> queue == NULL) {
        queue -> queue = newNode;
    }else{
        Node * addHere = getNextInsertionPointer(queue->queue);
        addHere = newNode;
        //heapify(queue);
    }
}
```

Comment: *seem to not add a properly*.... can you elaborate? Exactly what is the data you gave it and what result did you get that was incorrect? Also, I see code that traverses, and code that returns an insertion point. But I don't see any code that actually adds/inserts data.

Comment: Please read this: [ask]. Then apply this to your question, then you'll get better answers